# Deploying Kafka Consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are deploying kafka consumers based of Java API in a seperate VM grouped by usage. Probably 3-4 consumers (not in same group)/vm based on throughput of these consumers.

Is it best to use this method or deploy the consumer using dockers? Any pointers would be helpful.

Though you can use Kafka confluent REST proxy and others, my question is about consumer deployment.

Answer (score 1):

A VM has too much overhead for simply running one or few JVM applications. If you have a container platform, then that would be preferred, and would start the app faster than provisioning new VMs per app